# Select2 dropdown css modification

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2

I have this situation:

[image]

and I'd like to move the `.select2-dropdown .select2-dropdown--below` to `left: 0` and `witdth: 100%`(relative to the window). As you can see, I already added a `top` to it, but it doesn't work for the other properties.

I use the last version of the plugin.

I added an example. Do you see that hr? I'd like the dropdown to start from the left and be full width like the rule.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/770uxpmy/2/)

Comment: Can you please add code or JSFiddle link of your issue? It would be better to understand your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/770uxpmy/7/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/9w1Lgbt5/

This is css you need:

```
  span.select2-dropdown.select2-dropdown--below {
    top: 30px !important;    
    width:100vw !important;
    transform:translate(-100px,0) !important;
}
```

100vw means `viewport width`, and it will use 100% of the window width. Another problem was that  `span.select2-dropdown.select2-dropdown--below` is child of `select2` class (which is moved by 100px from the left). It was not possible before to change its left position without changing child element to `position:fixed` but with `transform` it is possible. 
First parametar is 100px is because whole select2 is moved `-100px`, so we have to translate child by 100px to the left to match window left position.